# .htaccess rules to redirect crawlers to another folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a single page app (react, react-router) and I am trying to redirect search and share bots/crawlers to a different folder with static snapshots of the app. I have a .htaccess setup which is mostly working but missing a few things.

- It is currently correctly redirecting from `domain.com/something` to `domain.com/snap/something/`
- Edit: It is now correctly redirecting `domain.com` to `domain.com/snap/`
- It does not handle `domain.com/non-existing`, it should redirect to `domain.com/snap/404.html` but currently redirects to `domain.com/snap/non-existing`

The .htaccess I have is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [L,R=301]

# For crawlers show snapshots
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} googlebot|bingbot|yandex|baiduspider|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora\ link\ preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(snap) [NC]
# Proxy the request
RewriteRule ^(?!.*?(\.js|\.css|\.xml|\.less|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.pdf|\.doc|\.txt|\.ico|\.rss|\.zip|\.mp3|\.rar|\.exe|\.wmv|\.doc|\.avi|\.ppt|\.mpg|\.mpeg|\.tif|\.wav|\.mov|\.psd|\.ai|\.xls|\.mp4|\.m4a|\.swf|\.dat|\.dmg|\.iso|\.flv|\.m4v|\.torrent|\.ttf|\.woff))(.*) /snap/$2/ [R=301,L]

# Don't rewrite files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the requested pattern is file and file doesn't exist, send 404
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(\/[a-z_\-\s0-9\.]+)+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]

# otherwise use history router
RewriteRule ^ /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Edit: I moved the crawler part of .htaccess up and it is now correctly handling `domain.com -> domain.com/snap/` scenario, but I can't figure out how to make it handle the non-existing routes.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect your `404` uris to the correct destination, you can use the following rule . Put this right bellow your `www to non-www` redirect rule block and make sure to clear your browser cache before testing  :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} googlebot|bingbot|yandex|baiduspider|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora\ link\ preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(snap) [NC]
# Proxy the request
RewriteRule ^(?!.*?(\.js|\.css|\.xml|\.less|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.pdf|\.doc|\.txt|\.ico|\.rss|\.zip|\.mp3|\.rar|\.exe|\.wmv|\.doc|\.avi|\.ppt|\.mpg|\.mpeg|\.tif|\.wav|\.mov|\.psd|\.ai|\.xls|\.mp4|\.m4a|\.swf|\.dat|\.dmg|\.iso|\.flv|\.m4v|\.torrent|\.ttf|\.woff))(.*) /snap/404.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Am I correct to assume that there isn't a pretty way to do this without duplicating code?